# Sorting a list in ascending order using a for loop repeatedly for binarySearch (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop, binary-search

I have a list of classes that I am attempting to sort in ascending order, by adding items in a for loop like so.

```
    private static void addObjectToIndex(classObject object) {
        for (int i=0;i<collection.size();i++)
        {
            if (collection.get(i).ID >= object.ID)
            {
                collection.insertElementAt(object, i);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (classObject.size() == 0)
            classObject.add(object);
    }
```

This is faster than sorting it every time I call that function, as that would be simpler but slower, as it gives O(N) time as opposed to using Collections.sort's O(N log N) every time (unless I'm wrong).

The problem is that when I run Collections.binarySearch to attempt to grab an item out of the Vector collection(The collection requires method calls on an atomic basis) it still ends up returning negative numbers as shown in the code below.

```
        Comparator<classObject> c = new Comparator<classObject>() 
        { 
            public int compare(classObject u1, classObject u2) 
            {
                int z1 = (int)(u1).ID;
                int z2 = (int)(u2).ID;
                if(z1 > z2)
                    return 1;
                return z2 <= z1 ? 0 : -1;
            }

        }; 
        int result = Collections.binarySearch(collection, new classObject(pID), c);
        if (result < 0)
            return null;
        if (collection.get(result).ID != pID)
            return null;
        else
            return collection.get(result);
```

Something like

```
result = -1043246
```

Shows up in the debugger, resulting in the second code snippet returning null.

Is there something I'm missing here? It's probably brain dead simple. I've tried adjusting the for loop that places things in order, <=, >=, < and > and it doesn't work. Adding object to the index i+1 doesn't work. Still returning null, which makes the entire program blow up.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are aware of `binarySearch()`, why don't you use it in `addObjectToIndex()` too?

Answer (score 1):

Boy, did you get here from the 80s, because it sure sounds like you've missed quite a few API updates!

> This is faster than sorting it every time I call that function, as that would be simpler but slower, as it gives O(N) time as opposed to using Collections.sort's O(N log N) every time (unless I'm wrong).

You're now spending an O(n) investment on every insert, So that's O(n^2) total, vs the model of 'add everything you want to add without sorting it' and then 'at the very end, sort the entire list', which is O(n logn).

> Vector is threadsafe which is why I'm using it as opposed to something else, and that can't change

Nope. Threadsafety is not that easy; what you've written isn't thread safe.

Vector is obsolete and should never be used. What Vector does (vs. ArrayList) is that each **individual** operation on a vector is thread safe (i.e. atomic). Note that you can get this behaviour from any list if you really need it with: `List<T> myList = Collections.synchronizedList(someList);`, but it is highly unlikely you want this.

Take your current impl of `addObjectToIndex`. it is not atomic: It makes *many* different method calls on your vector, and these have zero guarantee of being consistent. If two threads both call `addObjectToIndex` and your computer has more than one core, than you will eventually end up with a list that looks like: `[1, 2, 5, 4, 10]` - i.e., not sorted.

Take your addObjectToIndex method: That method just doesn't work properly unless its view of your collection is consistent for the entirety of the run. In other words, that block needs to be 'atomic' - it either does it all or does none of it, and it needs a consistent view throughout. Stick a `synchronized` around the entire block. In contrast to Vector, which considers each individual call atomic and nothing else, which doesn't work here. More generally, 'just synchronize' is a rather inefficient way to do multicore - the various collections in the `java.util.concurrent` are usually vastly more efficient and much easier to use, you should read through that API and see if there's anything that'll work for you.

> `if(z1 > z2) return 1;`

I'm pretty sure your insert code sorts ascending, but your comparator sorts descending. Which would break the binary search code (the binary search code is specced to return arbitrary garbage if the list isn't sorted, and as far as the comparator you use here is concerned, it isn't). You should use the same comparator anytime it is relevant, and not re-implement the logic multiple times (or if you do, at least test it!).

There is also no need to write all this code.

```
Comparator<classObject> c = Comparator::comparingInt(co -> co.ID);
```

is all you need.

**However**

It looks like what you really want is a collection that keeps itself continually sorted. Java has that; it's called a `TreeSet`. You pass it a Comparator (or you don't, and TreeSet expects that the elements you put in have a natural order, either is fine), and it will keep the collection sorted, at very cheap cost (*far* better than your O(n^2)!), continually. It *IS* a set, meaning if the comparator says that 2 items are equal, then adding both to the set results in the second `add` call being ignored (sets cannot contain the same element more than once, and for a TreeSet, 'the same element' is defined solely by 'comparing them returns 0' - TreeSet ignores hashCode and equals entirely).

This sounds like what you really want. If you need 2 different objects with the same ID to be added anyway, then add some more fields to your comparator (instead of returning 0 upon same ID, move on to checking the insertion timestamp or whatnot). But, with a name like 'ID', sounds like duplicates aren't going to happen.

The reason you want to use this off-the-shelf stuff is because otherwise you need to do it yourself, and if you're going to endeavour to write it yourself, you need to be a good programmer. Which you clearly aren't (yet - we all started a newbie and learned to become good later, it's the natural order of things). For example, if I try to add an element to a non-empty collection where the element I try to add has a larger ID than anything in the collection, it just won't add anything. That's because you wrote `if (classObject.size() == 0) classObject.add(object);` but you wanted `classObject.add(object);` without the `if`. Also, In java we write `ClassObject`, not `ClassObject`, and more generally, `ClassObject` is a completely meaningless name. Find a better name; this helps code be less confusing, and this question does suggest you could use some of that.

Comment: ClassObject not ClassObject? That's exactly the same thing. Your post is extremely informative, but you need to work on your tone when you address people. Calling them a bad programmer isn't good social skills in any form, patronizing them when you don't know anything about them is something else. I digress, the reason I'm using Vector is because you don't know the context of the entire program I'm working on. The program DOES require atomic method calls on an individual basis. So no, a TreeSet will not work in this case.

Comment: Well, in your own paste you wrote 'classObject'; I assume you figured it out. Apparently you are of the opinion that it is insulting to inform people that when you're taking your first steps in an entirely new and quite complicated profession, that they aren't very good at it yet. Well, let me be the first to console you: I __sucked__ when I started. Boy was I bad. I would hope you don't hold a newbie (or yourself) to the vaunted standards you sure seem to be holding them to, because that seems quite unfair and unrealistic.

Comment: @ProgrammerMan I think this answer has everything you need; once you find your way past your digression in trying to teach me and get back to trying to help yourself get past this question, you may for example consider that if Collections.synchronizedList exists, Collections.synchronizedSet may also exist. I won't leave you on hot coals: It does.

Comment: This ended up being terrible advice, set us back a bit because you can't just substitute a TreeSet for a Vector, it lead to a ton of design problems, and we ended up generating a custom class that worked like Vector yet kept a secondary list that was sorted that we fed through internal method calls to deal with it.